# IN IE6, how to position transparent PNG using filter?

Tags: css, png, transparent, internet-explorer-6

I have following CSS:

```
background-div:  url(/images/top.png) no-repeat top center;
```

and I am using the following filter for IE6: ( Transparent PNG Hack)

```
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader
   (src='/images/top_arrow.png',sizingMethod='scale');
```

How can I add the background position (i.e. top center) to the filter?

Comment: This approach caused my site to completely break in IE8&9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are heavy restrictions on this method and you cannot add the background position.

Let me suggest trying out [this method](http://www.twinhelix.com/css/iepngfix/demo/) instead, it allows much more flexibility than the simple approach you're doing now.  It's been engineered over the years and is the best fix I've encountered (and there are quite a few fixes out there.)